# C++ equivalent for memset on char*

Tags: c++, memcpy, memset

I have this code

```
  char * oldname = new char[strlen(name) + 1];

  memcpy(oldname,name,strlen(name) + 1);

  name = new char[strlen(oldname) + strlen(r.name) + 1];
  memset(name, '\0', strlen(name));

  strcat(name,oldname);
  strcat(name," ");
  strcat(name,r.name);
```

I understand that it is a no no to use memcpy and memset but I haven't understood exactly how to use this in C++, preferably without std.

Does anyone know? Thank you.

Comment: It seems you may have allocated one character too little for name. And I don't quite see why you fill the array with zeros in the first place, if you are going to overwrite it thereafter. (The first strcat requires only the first character to be null, strcpy wouldn't require even that. Both these functions null-terminate the string for you.) Oh, and `strlen(name)` will not work very nicely, unless the string already contains a properly terminated c-string! It doesn't do anything else than count all the characters up to the first null character.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
char * oldname = new char[strlen(name) + 1];

    //memcpy(oldname,name,strlen(name) + 1);
    strcpy(oldname,name);

    name = new char[strlen(oldname) + strlen(r.name) + 1];
    //memset(name, '\0', strlen(name));
    name[0] = '\0';

    strcat(name,oldname);
    strcat(name," ");
    strcat(name,r.name);
```

I understand this now, just wanted to paste this code for all future visitors
The commented lines are equivalent with the uncommented ones below them. C commented, C++ uncommented.

Comment: that is wrong. the commented line is not equivalent to name[0] = '\0'

Answer (score 13):

In general, there's `std::fill`. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/

Or in this particular instance, you should consider using `std::vector<char>`.

(Note that `memset` can still be used in C++ if you use `#include <cstring>`, although it's less idiomatic in C++.)

Answer (score 12):

One possible replacement for `memset` when you have an array of object types is to use the `std::fill` algorithm. It works with iterator ranges and also with pointers into arrays.

`memcpy` calls can usually be replaced with calls to `std::copy`.

e.g.

```
std::copy(name, name + strlen(name) + 1, oldname);
// ...
std::fill(name, name + strlen(name), '\0');
```

`memset` and `memcpy` are still there and can be used when appropriate, though. It's probably a bigger no-no from many C++ developer's point of view to be using a raw `new` and not using a resource managing object. It's much better to use a `std::string` or a `std::vector<char>` so that memory deallocation is automatic and the code is more exception safe.

Comment: `std::fill_n` might be a better match than fill. Otherwise, good answer, +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that it is a no no to use memcpy and memset but I haven't understood exactly how to use this in C++, preferably without std.

It's not a no-no to use `memcpy` and `memset` when their use is appropriate. Why should it be?

There's `std::copy` in C++ that copies a set of items (works on any type and not just `char*`) from an iterator to another.

Comment: But is the use appropriate when it can be replaced with the safer, and potentially more efficient `std::fill`?

Comment: @jalf: There's no doubt that `std::fill` should be preferred to `memset` in general *when it can be used*. My point was there's usually no language feature that you'll throw out completely. One example is some piece of code that needs to be compiled in C as well as C++.

Answer (score 2):

Other than the inconvenience of having to manually copy and do all the memory allocation yourself, there's nothing wrong with that C++ code.

I would, however, strongly encourage the use of `std::string` for string manipulation in C++.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just doing string manipulation, use string.

Answer (score 1):

To copy from a to b, take `std::copy(src_start,src_end,dest_start)` which increments `src_start` and copies it to the next destination element until `src_start==src_end` is met.

```
memcpy(oldname,name,strlen(name)+1)
// is the same as
std::copy(name,name+strlen(name)+1,oldname)
```

.. except it will also work for non-PODs, and you don't need to mess with byte lengths if a single element is more than one byte.

However, if you just want to do string manipulation, the `std::string` class (and `std::wstring` for wide char strings) are provided. Concatenating them is as simple as:

```
std::string s = "name",s2 = ..,s3 = ..;
s = s2+s+s3+"Hello";
```

Nothing keeps you from using the `strxxx` family of functions in C++, but I'd highly recommend you to switch to `std::string`and rest of the STL. It's not perfect either, but much less error-prone.